# No me adjunta el fichero como pdf, phpmailer desde google drive

Tags: php, phpmailer, google-api

Tengo la siguiente situación:

Estoy adjuntando un fichero **pdf**, que esta en **google drive** usando **phpmailer**. Lo que me sucede, es que cuando envío el correo con el adjunto, al descargar el fichero para la máquina me dice que no se puede abrir y si lo trato de abrir desde el cliente de **Gmail** me lo abre pero no como un documento **pdf** sino como un documento que se puede editar.

Cuando trato de abrir el documento de **pdf** con el lector de **pdf** me dice el siguiente mensaje:

> El tipo de archivo documento **HTML (text/html)** no está permitido

El código que estoy usando para adjuntar el archivo es el siguiente:

**Lectura del fichero:**

```
    $path = "https://drive.google.com/open?id=18hMk_9TmC3dsCjwe0RQ1Ka-qaqs4uMcD"
    $fichero = file_get_contents($path);
```

**Métodos del phpmailer para el adjunto**

```
$xmail->addStringAttachment($fichero,comprobante.pdf);
```

Gracias.

Comment: El problema es que tu fichero no está compartido en modo público, se necesita permiso para abrirlo, por tanto es imposible que se adjunte al correo mediante PHPMailer.

Comment: Gracias no me había percatado de ese detalle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya logre resolver el problema que tenia. Les dejo aquí como fue que lo solucione por si a otra persona le da este error que me dio a mi. La solución la hice usando la la misma **api** de **google-drive** que tiene un ejemplo para descargar los archivos. En lugar de usar el método **file_get_contents()** use el ejemplo que esta en la **api**. A continuación les dejo el código:

```
$response = $service->files->get($fileId, array(
    'alt' => 'media'));
$fichero = $response->getBody()->getContents();
```

**$fileId** (es el id del archivo en google-drive)

[Link del ejemplo de Google-Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#downloading_a_file)